# Refreshing the page using Ajax

Tags: ajax

How to refresh the page using Ajax? I mean pure Ajax, without any libraries used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Ajax -- just vanilla javascript will do:

```
location.reload();
```

http://www.netlobo.com/javascript_location_reload.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reload the current page using javascript:

```
location.reload()
```

or

```
history.go(0)
```

or

```
location.href = location.href
```